# Basic regex fail even though online validators mark it as correct

Tags: regex, kotlin

I have a basic regex for checking if string has at least one digit -

```
if (!("^(?=.*[0-9])".toRegex().matches(registerInput.input))) {
     // Warn user
}
```

However, even with an input `123`, it fails and goes into `// Warn user` section.

I used online validation tools and it seems nothing is wrong with my regex. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with kotlin, but I looked up kotlin regex to see whether you really needed to anchor your regex to the start of the string.

The description for the `match` method, is:

> Indicates whether the regular expression matches the entire input.

Which isn't going to be true for your example. It looks like `containsMatchIn` is a better option:

```
if (!("[0-9]".toRegex().containsMatchIn(registerInput.input))) {
    // Warn user
}
```

If you're just searching for a match, you don't need to anchor your regex to the start of a string, or use fancy look-ahead groups or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Following SpoonMeiser's answer, the positive lookahead test will match if you add what is need to get the entire input matched:

```
if (!("^(?=.*[0-9]).*$".toRegex().matches("123")))
```

Because `^(?=.*[0-9])` *matches only the beginning* of the line (looked-ahead characters aren't taken, or "consumed").

So to match the whole line, just add `.*$` after.

Of course, this is overkill in this context, SpoonMeiser'answer is way much better.